# VoIP using PjSIP : pjsua_acc.c SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)

Tags: voip, sip, pjsip

I am trying to run test VoIP program as given in http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm

I am trying public SIP servers present at http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/sip/servers.html

But I always get error message as

14:33:25.515    pjsua_acc.c  SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)

I never used SIP before, I am not able to guess where the problem is. Is there any simple way to test SIP servers? Does anybody know public free SIP server that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 408 timeout message typically means that the user agent, in this case your pjsip application, sent it's request but did not get a response.

I'm involved in a free SIP service called [sipsorcery](http://www.sipsorcery.com) that you can test your software with. It lets you view a full trace of your SIP messages with either a Silverlight browser application or telnet console which is extremely handy when trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your SIP client locally with [SIPP](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/).
It can process REGISTER requests as well as all other SIP messages.
In addition you can write xml scripts for SIPP for other complex scenarios.