# Twilio Phonegap plugin pjsip error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, twilio, pjsip

I am stuck at this from few days. I installed the phonegap plugin for twilio client (by Jeff Linwood) to a fresh phonegap app. Copied the headers, library file to xcode project from twilio ios sdk as mentioned in instructions.

But when i run the test app, it gives me following error:

> 2014-12-14 12:30:42.940 TestApp[1802:14622] THREAD WARNING:
>   ['TCPlugin'] took '221.611084' ms. Plugin should use a background
>   thread. 2014-12-14 12:30:42.941 TestApp[1802:14622] PJSIP(1):
>   pjsua_acc.c  .Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy
>   (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001] 2014-12-14 12:30:43.947
>   TestApp[1802:14622] State: Offline 2014-12-14 12:30:45.727
>   TestApp[1802:14777] PJSIP(2):    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration
>   failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily) 2014-12-14 12:30:45.734
>   TestApp[1802:14777] PJSIP(1):    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to
>   create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]

Tested with following :

- Xcode v 6.1.1/iOS 8.1 and XCode 5.1.1/iOS 7.1 (both alternatively)

  - Phonegap version : 4.1.2-0.22.9 and 3.6.3-0.22.3 (both alternatively)
  - Cordova iOS 4.1.2 and 3.7.0 (both alternatively)
  - Twilio iOS Client SDK 1.2

If you need any more info please feel free to ask.
Please suggest me if i am doing anything wrong.
It would be great if someone can help me to go through this.
Regards.

Comment: I can't specifically tell you how to fix this, but I do recognize the errors...  
  
Registraion in progress already ---> .Unable to create/send 
REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]  
  
You shouldn't get a redirect, check the sip server address ----> ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)  
Same as previous ---> .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]  
This may offer some guidance:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623816/voip-using-pjsip-pjsua-acc-c-sip-registration-failed-status-408-request-time

Comment: I'm having the exact same warning (it's not an error per se, because everythng works as intended), but I'd like to know what the issue is here, and how to get rid of it! Hence the bounty :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without some code sample it's hard to say for certain, but as mentioned it looks like there are multiple connect calls being made.

Looking at the source it appears that the "deviceSetup" command will start a connection, so if you are manually calling the "connect" command after setting up the device it will likely cause that warning. Feel free to post some more sample code if that doesn't work.

Hope that helps!